# Rename new document created in Document Library automatically when created

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, flow

In a document library folder, when a user creates a new document, instead of it being named 'Document' when created, I want it to be named as the last name of the user. I have explored trying to do this through a Flow but there does not seem to be a way to rename a document. The user cannot rename the document themselves as they do not have delete permission.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mike's link is very helpful. Do have a check on it. I made a sample flow works in my end. 
[image]

The"Test Library" is your library name.

The SP.Data part in the body needs to be checked via the following link

```
https://yourdomain.sharepoint.com/sites/yoursitehere_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Library name')?$select=ListItemEntityTypeFullName
```

[image]

The last outputs part is your required file name format.

[image]
[image]

Comment: The Flow fails with an error 'BadGateway'  "message": "The file or folder name contains characters that are not permitted.  Please use a different name." Not really sure what I did wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: @cflasrado would you like to show us your setting in the send an HTTP request action?

Comment: I updated my question with the image.

Comment: Ok, I managed to get it to work. However, the flow fails with the error the document is checked out to me. Is there a way to delay the flow until the document has been saved or checked back in?

Comment: @cflasrado change the trigger to when a file is created or modified. Then you can add a if condition on the " check out" property which will indicate the status of the file. Only send the http request when check out is false. I updated with a pic

Comment: thank you, this worked.

Comment: I have another problem with this. Everything works perfectly fine and the files do get renamed by the flow but after the file gets renamed, it triggers the flow again as the file has been modified. How would I get it to stop after succeeding once?

Comment: @cflasrado You can try to change the trigger to "when a file is created". Then the flow won't be triggered after the modification.

Comment: I added a Terminate action after the HTTP request and that solved the issue.Changing the trigger to "when a file is created" would lead me back to the issue of the flow failing when the document is checked out.

Comment: @cflasrado, Glad to here you figure it out. You are right, a termination action is better than  changing the trigger.

Answer (score 0):

This is a 2013 style workflow:

[image]

[image]

[image]

This simple demo grabs the full name, but you could use Find Substring in String and one of the Extract Substring actions to pull off the last name.

You will need to configure App permissions to let the workflow do what the user is not allowed to do. (rename)

Comment: Would this Flow work/be applicable on SharePoint Online because I do not see an action available to Set Name? I only see an action to Update Item or File.

Comment: The action is called "Set field in current item". The field being set is "Name".

Comment: I am using Flow and not SharePoint Designer and that action is not available on Flow. Is there a way to achieve what I am trying by using Flow?

Comment: Ah. Your question said workflow and was tagged workflow. Flow can call the SharePoint web services. This might apply: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Renaming-a-File-in-SharePoint-Online/td-p/176708